# AES Key Management in Offline Android App

Tags: java, android, database, encryption

**The Background**

I am working on an Android app which needs to store some very sensitive data about patients in a database. And this app must work and show all data in offline mode as well.

**What I Have Done**

As these data are highly sensitive and any theft of the devices should reveal these information to the hacker, I have encrypted these patient details before storing them in the database.

**The Problem**

As a major requirement of this app is to work 100% offline, I need to be able to decrypt all these sensitive data in offline mode as well.

Here comes the actual problem.

Where do I store my key then? I can store it in my server and everytime the app is opened, a network call would be made to fetch the key and then I can decrypt my data.

I can not do this, as my app needs to work in 100% offline mode. I need the ket available to me while in offline mode as well. So I have to cache the key somewhere.

Now, this is very risky, isn't it?

Any hacker getting hold of these devices can pull the databases and somehow manage to get hold of the key as well.

**Solution**

This seems to be a very tricky problem to me. How do I store the key properly so that no one can access it? I can not also go for password-based keys as passwords will be changed by the administrators of these devices sometime, then all the data encrypted with the old key would be unaccessible.

Is there any good way, if not full-proof to elegantly solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look onto the [AndroidKeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html). On devices with hardware based key store this should be a good security anchor.

Comment: It was introduced in API level 18, but my app should be supporting API level 14 and above.

Comment: If you want to support API14 you don't have to care about security. The OS is full of exploits so that every app can get root permission easily. If you really care about security set the minimum API to 19, better 21.

Comment: @Robert I can understand. But it is my clients requirement and I have no control over it. Is there a way I can generate the key using an algorithm and obfuscate the code using ProGuard? Will that help?

Comment: Well than I would respond to your client that you as an Android expert have evaluated that security comes at a price. Anyway you can use the AndroidKeyStore and make the use API specific (only use it when the app is running on API 18+). Proguard will not help you to keep anything secret. For a hacker a ProGuard protected app is like a cardboard box - while you need a safe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I would try to use the KeyStore then. Does the KeyStore store symmetric key, my initial research says it doesn't.

Comment: For API18 you need to use RSA keys. Symmetric keys require AFAIR API 20 or 21.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert.

Comment: Are your users able to remember a password for offline access?

Comment: Yes. The app should be accessible 100% offline as it would be used in hospitals and places with no internet at all. But the password is subject to change as the user may want to change his/her password any time.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Any help on this?

Comment: In that case, you only need a password-based encryption library. [Here](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor) is one that is secure.

Comment: Thanks for the library, but the problem still remains right. If the password is changed by the user, then any prior encrypted data will be unrecoverable.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Any help on this?

Comment: Well, if the user decides to change the password, you will need to decrypt the data and re-encrypt it with the new one again. This would be the case with every solution that you can come up with. Of course, this re-encryption could be made more efficient by having a data-encryption key (DEK) and a key-encryption key (KEK) where the KEK is derived from the password.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks a lot for your help. I should be following this approach only. Is this the best possible way, or there is anything else I can consider as a best practice as well?

Comment: There isn't usually a "best" approach, but rather a secure approach that works.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for all the help that you did. If you would like to put it as a proper answer, so that every one else coming to this question can quickly find the solution. I would be more than happy to accept it.